# send variable from route::post to route::get in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and actually never used it before
I have a showForm.blade.php where the form is present whose post request is transferred to route web.php

get route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    
    return view('showForm',['na'=>'']);
})->name("start");
```

post route

```
Route::post('/upload', function (Request $request) {
    
    if($request->file("thing")=="")
    {
        // return back()->withInput();
        return redirect()->route('start');
    }
    else
    {
        $name=$request->file("thing")->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::disk("google")->putFileAs("",$request->file("thing"),$name);
        $url=Storage::disk('google')->url($name);
        $details=Storage::disk("google")->getMetadata($name);
        $path=$details['path'];
        DB::insert('insert into books (Title, Url, FileId) values (?,?,?)', [$name,$url,$path]);
        return redirect()->route('start');
    }
})->name("upload");
```

I want that in post route
when if condition becomes true then along with redirecting to get route, it sends a variable `$msg="insert data";` and when else condition becomes true, it sends a variable `$msg="success upload";` which the get route will receive and use it in

```
return view('showForm',['na'=>$msg]);
```

to return the msg to the showForm.blade.php

how can I do this?
I have read that we can send the parameters by

```
return redirect()->route('start',['varaiable'=>'value'])
```

but where to specify that variable in get route so that can use it inside for the message so that the user will receive a different message according to the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see. It seems like you want to flash the message `insert data` after redirecting to another route. In that case, you can use the `with` method.

```
return redirect()->route('start')->with('message', 'Insert Data!');
```

Now this message will be kept in the session. On the start route blade template, you can do something as follows -

```
@if (session('message'))
    <h1>{{ session('message') }}</h1>
@endif
```

The message should show up. Once you refresh the page, it'll go away. Read the official docs for [HTTP Session](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php

namespace Emedico\Http\Controllers;

use Session;
use Redirect;

public function upload(Request $request)
{
    return Redirect::route('start', [variable => val]; 
}
```